# How to call a key in a dictionary if the value is matched?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this example dictionary of names and their jobs

```
my_dict = {'al': 'sales', 'tony': 'engineer': 'fred': 'support'}
```

I would like to print the name (key) of the entry in the dictionary if the job title (value) is match in an if statement.

```
job = input("what is the job?: ")

if job in my_dict.values():

   "print the key that has that job as a value"
```

How to do it?

Comment: Perhaps the key should be the job title, and the value for each job title a list of names?

Comment: `for key, value in my_dict.iteritems(): if (your condition): elif(your condition): `